# CLLocationManager not calling delegate in an NSObject

Tags: ios, delegates, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to create a helper class to get the coordinates of the phone in any other class easily. I've followed a tutorial in which the `UIViewController` implemented the `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` and it worked. I tried to do the same in a simple `NSObject`, but then my delegate was not called anymore.

This is the code I have :

PSCoordinates.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface PSCoordinates : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager* locationManager;


@end
```

PSCoordinates.m

```
#import "PSCoordinates.h"

@implementation PSCoordinates

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0f;
            NSLog(@"PSCoordinates init");
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Géolocalisation : %@",[newLocation description]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Géolocalisation (erreur) : %@",[error description]);

}


@end
```

I'm calling it by calling

```
PSCoordinates * coordinates = [[PSCoordinates alloc] init];
```

when pressing a button. The init is working as I can see the NSLog `PSCoordinates init`.

I've found other topics of people having the same problem but none of the answer solved it.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make "PSCoordinates * coordinates" as global in your class. It will work :)

Comment: You're a boss ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks it really help me, But do you know Why it is so ?

Comment: @h.kishan Because ARC is enabled for your project and you are declaring the variable 'coordinates' as local. Compiler will add a release message to this instance the very next moment when its find the scope of the object is over. So, your instance is already released and exist no more. So your delegate will not work.

When you declare variable as global, it will exists until its parent class exists. So your delegate will get called.

Comment: Thats the answer !! GREAT :)

Comment: @AugustinePA how do you make it global in Swift 2.0, any ideas?

Comment: You saved the day! Like 4 years after! Thanks!